# CSS 3 gradients distortion for diagonal effect

Tags: macos, css, google-chrome, opera

I am trying to use css3 to create a gradient which runs diagonal at a particular percentage but it seems that sharp look is getting distorted. Perhaps i am missing something here, any ideas or suggestions welcome.

[image]

Associated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/abhinandan/ckaobdpv/

and CSS3 code used:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    height: 9em;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(72, 208, 231) 30%,#f6f6f6 30%, #222 100%);
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Seems like issue is seen in certain environments for example Chrome on Mac, Opera on Windows

Comment: I don’t see that “distortion” in Chrome.

Comment: I see it in chrome and safari, just try to resize.

Comment: I did resize it, didn’t see it at any size.

Comment: Hmm ! thanks for info it seems an issue with chrome on os x Yosemite. not sure why though.

Comment: @Abhi: It happens for me on Opera (Windows 8.1) when I try to re-size and I have seen this issue often with angled gradients but I don't think there is any 100% fool proof fix.

Comment: @Harry: so background image ?

Comment: Can't say mate. It depends. Very small distortions that happen only when resizing, I wouldn't mind them much but then hey I am not a professional designer.

Comment: Looks good to me on Safari on Yosemite but not on Chrome.

Comment: seems like a chrome issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the distortion between `rgb(72, 208, 231)` and `#f6f6f6` because you used the same percentages to fade from the first color to the second one.

So, what you have to do is to increase the percentage for the second color:

```
.header {
   position: relative;
   font-weight: 200;
   padding-top: 50px;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   height: 9em;
   background:-webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(72, 208, 231) 30%,#f6f6f6 50%, #222 100%);
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

The result:

[image: Gradient Result]

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CristianAlexandru92/c2m1es8a/)

Note that, I saw that distortion in Chrome for Windows.
**Also, make sure that you're using prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.**